# Number theory problem proof

Tags: number-theory

The problem is: Prove that $7|x^2+y^2$ only if  $7|x$  and  $7|y$ for  $x,y∈Z$.

I found a theorem in my book that allows to do the following transformation:
if $a|b$ and $a|c$ -> $a|(b+c)$

So, can I prove it like this: $7|x^2+y^2 =>7|x^2, 7|y^2 => 7|x*x,  7|y*y => 7|x, 7|y$ ?

I am not really sure because I have this simple example in my head that even if $6|18$ => $6|14+4$, $6 ∤ 14$ and $6 ∤ 4$.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Two different solutions to this problem are given here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1448957p8297603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a theorem that if a prime $p$ of the form $p \equiv 3\pmod4$, and $p \mid x^2+y^2$, then $p \mid x$ and $p \mid y$.

At your problem take $p=7$, and with the above theorem you are done.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant!

The book says if $a|b$ and $a|c\implies a|b+c$ and **not** the reverse.. The case you have is a simple contradiction.

As far the problem goes , I can give you a proceeding.

Take $x=7\alpha +\beta; y=7\gamma +\delta$ Find out what $x^2+y^2$ evaluates to. Check what must be necessary condition for $\beta$ and $\delta$ for $7$ to divide $x^2+y^2$

Comment: (+1) for actually reading and answering the question (as opposed to the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Work in the field $\;\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z=\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3\}$, compute all squares, then all sums of squares (a *Pythagoras' table* will be useful) and check $$x^2+y^2\equiv 0\mod7\iff (x\equiv 0)\wedge (y\equiv 0)\mod 7.$$